# Echo response to command in Shell (Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

Tags: ssh

(In order to skip the are you sure warning of the disk space)
I tried `apt-get install php && echo Y`
but it does not work. It still asks for the warning.

What I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The man page says you should use the `-y` option.

```
    -y, --yes, --assume-yes
            Automatic yes to prompts.  Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts
            and run non-interactively.  If an undesirable situation, such as
            changing a held package or removing an essential package, occurs
            then apt-get will abort.
```

That is to say:

```
apt-get -y install php
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand what && is actually doing, it tells the shell to run the following command if the earlier commands exits with success. So what you are asking for is `echo Y` if the install works, this is clearly not what you want.

You may have some success with

```
echo Y | apt-get install php
```

But you will have more success with reading the documentation where you will find

> ```
> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>         Automatic yes to prompts.  Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts
>         and run non-interactively.  If an undesirable situation, such as
>         changing a held package or removing an essential package, occurs
>         then apt-get will abort.
> ```

So

```
apt-get -y install php
```

is what you want.